# Qt: Unknown module(s) in QT: webview

Tags: webview, module, qt5, qt5.6

I just installed Qt 5.6 with the "Qt Unified installer" provided by Qt. Before the installation started, I made sure, that the "WebView" option in the installer was ticked. Unfourtunately, there is no WebView for Windows in the Qt installation directory (I searched the whole directory for a webview dll), only a library for Android. Why is the webview package missing for windows?

edit: I tried to use webengine instead, but unfourtunately I get a similar message: "Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine"

King Regards
Bernhard

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I figured it out. Unfortunately, the Qt installer isn't that intuitive (at least not for me). Selecting `WebView` as a component in the installer does not mean, that the corresponding libraries are automatically added. Per default Qt only installs the MingW toolchain and this toolchain can't compile `WebView/WebEngine`. In order to use `WebView/WebEngine` one must select the precompiled Visual Studio libraries in the installer. Furthermore Visual Studio needs to be installed on the system.After the installation, make sure that Qt Creator uses the Visual Studio compiler (you can specify that in the Qt Creator build kit settings).

Comment: Generally speaking, developers should avoid MinGW if they work on Windows. It is something to know.